# how can i get median values in days format using sql query , below is my table data

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, database, mysql-workbench

```
    mobile        date
 - 9833099876   -2019-01-23
 - 9833099876   -2019-02-02
 - 9833099876   -2019-02-02
 - 9833099876   -2019-03-16
 - 9833099876   -2019-05-20
```

and the required output should be like this:

```
9833099876  32 -->this is only for example , not the  answer
```

Comment: Please explain the calculation.  You have no integer column in your data, so the "32" is quite mysterious.  Also, medians for an even number of rows are indeterminate (depending on a definition of what you want in that case).

Comment: see like i have multiple dates for one id , from that how can i get median values in days format group by dates

Comment: I still don't understand "32" as an answer.  I would expect 2019-02-02.

Comment: i m just putting the example of my result,i will explain clearly , i need the gap days between 2019-02-02 and 2019-03-16     .......Please give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

WITH cte(con_mob,billsDate)
AS
(SELECT DISTINCT contact_mobile,
    bills_date
FROM 
    Sales_data 
WHERE
    contact_mobile IS NOT NULL 
    AND bills_date is NOT NULL
)

SELECT 
    con_mob,meadian_value = 
CASE
WHEN 
    count(billsDate) % 2 = 0
THEN
    DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(date,MIN(billsDate)),
    CONVERT(date,MAX(billsDate)))
ELSE
    DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(date,MIN(billsDate)),
    CONVERT(date,MAX(billsDate))) / 2
END
FROM (
SELECT 
    con_mob,billsDate,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(
PARTITION BY 
    con_mob ORDER BY billsDate
    ) AS Rownum,
COUNT(billsDate)
OVER (PARTITION BY con_mob) AS vstcnt
FROM 
    cte ct
    ) a 
WHERE
    vstcnt % 2 = 0 AND Rownum in(vstcnt/2,vstcnt/2 +1)
    OR 
    vstcnt % 2 <> 0 AND Rownum in(vstcnt/2,vstcnt/2 + 2)
GROUP BY 
    con_mob 
HAVING COUNT(billsDate) > 1

Comment: contact_mobile   Dates

7045942408 2019-06-22T15:20:00Z
7045942408 2019-07-29T14:09:00Z
7045942408 2019-08-02T16:19:00Z
7045942408 2019-09-09T11:34:00Z

Comment: Mobile_num    Median_Days

7045942408 4      ---->this is my output